# ¿Por qué en América se usa(ba) más «goma de mascar» que «chicle»?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, historia, inglés, náhuatl

En mi infancia, cuando la mayoría de doblajes y traducciones al español todavía se hacían en América en vez de aquí en España, recuerdo que **me chocaba mucho que al chicle lo llamasen 'goma de mascar'**: lo escuchaba en series de dibujos (como Scooby Doo), y lo leía en los cómics de Disney (sobre todo en aquellos en los que aparecían los sobrinos del pato Donald).
Al principio no le daba mayor importancia. «Una de esas cosas que se dice distinto en Sudamérica», solía pensar. Luego aprendí que en inglés se dice *'chewing gum'*, y entonces pasé a achacarlo a la influencia anglosajona.

Sin embargo, a día de hoy sé que 'chicle' es en realidad un vocablo indígena de Centroamérica:

> [**chicle**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8jcrPyk)
>   Del náhuatl *tzictli*.

Y también que así es como se llama a esta golosina en México, el país que precisamente más influencia anglosajona tiene.

Me asalta la duda entonces: **¿por qué en otros países se usa, o se usó, 'goma de mascar' en vez de 'chicle', si esta última forma es más "autóctona" por así decirlo?**

Comment: En Chile se usa la palabra "chicle"... Y también sufrimos las traducciones hechas en España.

Comment: Idea. Aunque hubiera una palabra autóctona, si se popularizó de la mano de compañías norteamericanas (especialmente si se presentaba como un producto distinto, p.ej. "chicle de fresa") no sería tan raro que el término norteamericano se hiciera popular. Por ejemplo, por un tiempo pareció que "danone" se hacía casi tan popular como "yogurt", y eso que el nombre clásico era bien conocido.

Comment: walen - De acuerdo, con lo de la influencia de EEUU en México (aunque no sé si se ganaría el  premio de *mayor influencia*).  Pero quería preguntar si puedes aclarar, ¿podrías dar algunos ejemplos de países donde se usa "goma de mascar"?  Gracias.

Comment: @walen -  Pues no entiendo por qué dices que en América se usa(ba) más «goma de mascar» que «chicle».  Es decir, ¿cómo sabes que es/era así?  O, ¿por qué sospechabas que era así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soy mexicano y acá se usa chicle.

Durante una época y en medios de comunicación se popularizó el desuso de nahuatlismos pero afortunadamente esos días quedaron en el pasado y ahora se da más atención a la identidad propia del pueblo mexicano.

Esto ocurrió entre las décadas de los 70 y hasta los 90 en su mayoría por traducciones realizadas de España que empezaron a impregnar el estilo.

Comment: Pero Mike, ¿acaso se dejó de decir "chicle" durante ese periodo?

Comment: los medios de comunicacion usaban goma de mascar en lugar de chicle

Comment: Ah, ahí está mi problema.  He visto muy poca televisión.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de hacer una diferenciación, como bien lo indicas: el **chicle**, o **tzictli** en náhuatl, es una savia gomosa, un poco dura, aromática y de sabor ligeramente dulce que se obtiene del árbol *Manikara zapota*, conocido como chicozapote, el cual es originario de México y crece también en zonas tropicales de América central y sur. Es una resina vegetal y biodegradable, las empresas obtenían esa resina y de ahí fabricaban los **chicles**. Si te das cuenta, extraer esa resina de los árboles no es un proceso sencillo ni barato, por lo cual, los estadounidenses y la compañía Goodyear (si... la que fábrica llantas) crearon un sustituido para la resina llamado acetato polivinílico (mucho más barato). Goodyear fabrica buena parte de ese plástico neutro que sirve como base gomosa de lo que se conoce como **goma de mascar**. Así que la próxima vez que adquieras un "**chicle**" puedes ver en los componentes si realmente es un **chicle** que viene de un árbol mexicano o simplemente una **goma de mascar** de plástico.